# Why was I answered "yes it did" for this question "has the payment gone through?"?

Tags: tense, past-tense, questions, past-perfect, past-vs-past-perfect

I made an order through the net and as I was not sure  my payment had gone through I sent an email(just after ordering) to be sure that the seller received it . So I asked "has my payment gone through?"

A few hours after I received his answer "yes it did" . I was surprised that he answered "yes it did" I thought he would have said "yes it has"
The seller is a native american
Why did he answer "yes it did"?

Comment: One possibility is that he misremembered the exact phrasing of your original question, and was thinking that you had asked "Did my payment go through?"  In which case "Yes, it did" would be a correct response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When talking about the very recent past, many (not all) Americans use the simple past (something happened, did something happen? Yes, it did) whereas British speakers are much more likely to use the present perfect tense (something has happened, has something happened? Yes, it has).

Comment: You mean present perfect has happened